# C# - XmlSerializer only gets first XML element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to serialize an XML string and bind it to classes.  The problem is, the `XmlSerializer` only gets the first element of my XML string.

```
var xml = @"<cars>
                <car>
                    <make>Ford</make>
                    <model>Mustang</model>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </car>
                <car>
                    <make>Infiniti</make>
                    <model>G35</model>
                    <color>Red</color>
                </car>
            </cars>";

using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cars), new XmlRootAttribute("cars"));

    var r = (cars)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Here is the class I'm trying to bind to:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class cars
{
    public carsCar car { get; set; }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class carsCar
{
    public object make { get; set; }
    public object model { get; set; }
    public object color { get; set; }
}
```

I tried changing this

```
public carsCar car { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
public List<carsCar> car { get; set; }
```

But then my `List<carsCar>` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy your xml to the clipboard and then, in Visual Studio, go to Edit, Paste Special, Paste XML as Classes it will generate the correct class structure. You can tweak these classes to have the names you want and data types you want. Then your code will work, `r.car` will be an array of cars.

[image]

```
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class cars
{

    private carsCar[] carField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("car")]
    public carsCar[] car
    {
        get
        {
            return this.carField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.carField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class carsCar
{

    private string makeField;

    private string modelField;

    private string colorField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string make
    {
        get
        {
            return this.makeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.makeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string model
    {
        get
        {
            return this.modelField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.modelField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.colorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.colorField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for you?   That's exactly what I did but as I mentioned in the post.  r.car is an empty array for some reason.  If I make a list or array they are empty.  I generated the class with c# Paste Special

Comment: Ok thank you.  I re-generated the class and it worked.  I must have messed up something in the class when I changed names around and removed the private fields.  I'm getting the same results as you now.  Thanks!